# How to determine North-facing, south, east and west forest edges in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, flow-direction

I am using QGIS.

I have a shapefile with 41 polygons representing forest patches. I want to assess the effect the forest edge direction has on vegetation within the forest patches. I have defined forest edge as anything below 50 metres from the edge.

The shapefile looks like below:

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 41 
extent      : 645193.1, 708670.9, 5448161, 5555988  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 3
names       : id,      name,    area 
min values  :  1, foreat_20, 1078038 
max values  :  9,  forest_9,  950149
```

My dem looks like below:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4161, 2450, 10194450  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 25.91215, 25.91685  (x, y)
extent     : 645191.3, 708676.1, 5448150, 5555990  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : dem_30m 
values     : 273, 641  (min, max)
```

How do I determine which forest edge is facing the north and which one faces the south?

Comment: Do you need that DEM for this? Or do you mean an edge with a slope facing north/south etc? Because you can run a "slope and aspect" computation on your DEM to get the direction and angle from elevations, and overlay that with the polygons...

Comment: I mean an edge facing either north/south and i am not sure whether i need the DEM as well..

Comment: So when you say "below 50 metres from the edge" do you mean anywhere in the forest that is less than 50 metres from the edge of the forest? Like a negative buffer of size 50m? Its just that "below" could mean "below" in terms of height...

Comment: I mean all the forest from the forest boundary up to 50 into the forest is what constitutes forest edge. Anything above 50 metres deeper inside is the interior

Comment: What do you want as output? Computing the direction of the polygon is easy enough (answer below) but expanding that out to an area buffer of 50m inside the forest polygons is trickier. Is that what you want? As a raster?

Comment: @Spacedman So in the end, I want to compare south facing edges to those facing the north. So i will probably use this to mask the forest and do a regression on NDVI! Forgive my basic scientific language

Comment: @PolyGeo, I am using both R and QGIS!

Comment: If you wish to also ask about how to do this using R instead, then please do so in a separate question and include a code attempt that illustrates what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use "Force right-hand-rule" so that all polygons are in the same direction.
2. Convert "polygons to lines".
3. "Explode lines" to simple linear features (each feature is two points)
4. use Field Calculator to add a new field, `angle` to attribute table of exploded lines as expression:

```
(((azimuth( point_n( $geometry,1), point_n($geometry, 2)) + pi()) * 180/pi()) + 90 ) % 360
```

or maybe subtract 90 instead of adding. Doesn't make much difference to interpreting the values eventually.

5. "Buffer" exploded lines.
6. "Clip" buffered exploded lines to original forest polygons.

That should get you a layer where each line segment in your forest polygon is now an internal buffer polygon which you can colour by angle, giving this:

[image]

Oops thats the image when I didn't force the right hand rule. note the little polygon has red on its N side and the big polygon has red on the S side - that's because they were digitised in opposite directions. Making a version with a forced right-hand-rule fixes this:

[image]

now they agree. S is yellowy, W blue, E orange and so on.

note that there may be many overlaps where the polygon is made of lots of small features. Here's a version with hatched areas and lines of each cropped buffer visible:

[image]

Those overlapping areas are actually less than 50m from two segments of the polygon so their angle to the edge of the forest might not be well defined. In extremis thin bits of forest could be facing in two opposite directions, eg this one has a "point" that is close to a NW and a SE edge.

[image]

You may have to figure out how to deal with that.

If you are planning to work in a raster space at some point, it might be easier to rasterize the buffer area and then compute the angle from each raster point to the nearest point on the polygon. Which probably has a function somewhere... But this is the best vector-based approach I can come up with.